# How to put custom bootstrap theme in Angular 12?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an angular website with bootstrap from npm and the @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap. I really don't like the default theme. So I found some themes on bootswatch. and I downloaded the '_variables.scss' and the '_bootswatch.scss'.

In my style.css I had the following code working:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

in my angular.json I put the following style config:

```
...
"styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/_variables.scss",
              "src/_bootswatch.scss"             
            ],
..
```

.

And then I got the following error:

```
./src/_bootswatch.scss.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[1].use[0]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[1].use[1]!./src/_bootswatch.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
   ╷
15 │   font-family: $headings-font-family;
   │                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  src/_bootswatch.scss 15:16  root stylesheet

./src/_bootswatch.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
```

I really will appreciate help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're importing Bootstrap once and the other SCSS are not doing anything.

Create a new file in your src root (I like to create a new folder called 'styles' to keep it all neat, so put the other scss files there as well):

`src/styles/styles.scss`

In this new file, add imports in same order:

```
@import "_variables.scss" (the first one takes precedance)
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import "_bootswatch.scss"
```

Your `angular.json` should only have your `scss` since all gets compiled:

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.scss",
],
```

That's it. Also note, that I like to create a new file `_bootstrap.scss` instead of importing the one from `node_modules`, so I can remove the components I don't care about from Bootstrap like carousel.